# For $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with $f(1)=1$, $f(2n)=f(n)$, $f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)$, show that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

> Question: A function $f : ℕ \rightarrow ℕ$ is defined by $f(1)=1$, and for all $n\geq 1$,
>   $$f(2n)=f(n)$$
>   $$f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)$$
>   Prove that the range of $f$ is $ℕ$.

Thoughts: I was first thinking to prove this by showing that the first function will always yield a positive integer because f(2) = 1 and it is only defined by f(1)=1, meaning if it is a negative number of decimal, it won't work. Also, I was guessing that the first function was for even numbers. But... I got a little stuck on proving the range for the second function. Using the same logic as before, I presumed that the second function was meant for odd numbers as any odd number can be represented by 2n+1. However, I don't know how to properly show that the range is only restricted to natural numbers as I'm guessing I can't simply say that it is not defined when it is anything but a natural number.

Am I going in the wrong direction with my thinking?

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Since $f(x)$ returns sum of all digits of binary expansion of $x$, the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Suggestion: write out the values $f(1), f(2), f(3),$ .... Find pattern(s) from which you can figure out why the range is N. THEN try to explain why it's true (I.e. Write a proof).

Answer (score 1):

If $f(2^n +1)=n+1$ for all $n$, we get

$$\{2,3,4,...\} \subseteq f( \mathbb N).$$

Since $f(1)=1$  we derive

$$\mathbb N =\{1,2,3,4,...\} \subseteq f( \mathbb N).$$

From $f( \mathbb N) \subseteq \mathbb N$ we then conclude that $f( \mathbb N) =\mathbb N$ .

Comment: Thank you, but I meant to ask why $f(2^n+1)=n+1$ is used. Why did they use $2^n$ instead of $2n$? How did they get that from the functions?

Answer (score 0):

note that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, and $f(0)=0$. also every positive integer can be written uniquely as $2^nk$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in \{1,3,5,\dots \}$

it is easy to show that $f(2n+1) - f(2n-1) = f(n+1) - f(n-1)$ from which for every odd $k$:

$$
f(2^n k +1) - f(2^n k - 1)  = f(k+1) - f(k-1)
$$

and the RHS is zero unless $k=1$