# Proof Verification for the range of $f$ given certain conditions

Tags: functions, proof-verification

> Question: A function $f : ℕ \rightarrow ℕ$ is defined by $f(1)=1$, and for all $n\geq 1$,
>   $$f(2n)=f(n)$$
>   $$f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)$$
>   Prove that the range of $f$ is $ℕ$.

I had previously asked about this here: [For $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with $f(1)=1$, $f(2n)=f(n)$, $f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)$, show that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316977/for-f-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-with-f1-1-f2n-fn-f2n1-fnfn1)

Considering all the answers that the users gave, I have come up with the following proof for the problem:

"To show that the range of f is $ℕ$, we must make use of the fact that $f(2^n) = 1$ for all non-negative integers n. This is true because

$f(2^n)=f(2^{n-1})=f(2^{n-2})=\cdots=f(1)=1$.

For example:

$f(8)=f(4)=f(2)=1$ as $f(2n)=n$

Using this, we will prove that $f(2^n+1)=n+1$ for all $n\geq1$. A base case for this would be n=0:
$f(2^0+1)=f(1+1)=f(2)=f(1)=1$, with the end result, 1, being equal to n+1 (in this case, 0+1)

Next, suppose that we already know that $f(2^n+1)=n+1$. Through induction, it suffices to show that $f(2^{n+1}+1)=n+2$. Since $2^{n+1}+1$ is odd, we have:

$f(2^{n+1}+1)=f(2^n)+f(2^n+1)=1+(n+1)=n+2$.

The second part of the equality above was reached using the fact that $f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)$. This completes our induction. We have shown that $f(2^n+1)=n+1$ for all positive integers (including 0). Also, $f(1)=1$, which further supports 1 being in the range of $f$. Hence, the range of $f$ is $ℕ$."

Is this a strong proof? Do I need to add more details? I'm open to any suggestions!

Comment: You should mention the start of the induction, i.e the case $n=1$.

Comment: @Riquelme I've already mentioned $f(2^n)=1$; or are you saying to prove $f(2^n+1)=n+1$?

Comment: your proof looks really good now

Answer (score 2):

Overall it seems fine, a really good proof.

The main nitpick I have lies with how you did the induction and phrased your reasoning. Bear in mind that showing $f(2^n + 1) = n+1 \implies f(2^{n+1} + 1) = n+2$ neither completes the proof (just the inductive step), nor does it show by itself that it holds for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$.

Rather, this latter conclusion is given by the base case alongside the induction. You take a base case of $n=0$ (showing $f(1) = 1$). Induction gives us a phenomenon of "this step implies the next," a sort of domino effect if you will, but in typical induction you will need a starting point, a first domino to knock over. From that base case and the induction, you get that $P(0) \implies P(1) \implies P(2) \implies \cdots$ as you want (where $P(k)$ means "this result holds when $n=k$").

Since your base case is $n=0$ and is true, and since the induction holds, by these **together** you can conclude that your result holds for all $n \in \Bbb N$. If your base case was $n=10$, for example, you couldn't say this, only that it holds for integers $n \ge 10.$ (Another distinction is that you seem to imply it only holds for $n$ a positive integer. Technically since it holds for $n=0$, that should be included too. In this paragraph I use $\Bbb N$ synonymously with the nonnegative integers, i.e. including $0$.)

Thus in the future, it might be best to open your induction proof with the base case, and also to pay greater mind to which values of $n$ the proposition is valid (or whatever index you choose to use).

These are largely pedantic issues - ones worth noting, since clarity in your writing is important, but the core of your proof is valid. Good job!

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback - I will keep it in mind whenever I use induction. I edited my proof to match up to your comments - is it okay now?

Comment: "We have shown that f(2n+1)=n+1 for all positive integers (including 0)" -- I would just reword the ending to say "all nonnegative integers." To say 0 is included in the positive integers isn't quite correct (it's neither positive nor negative). I also feel like saying $f(1)1$ later on in the proof is a little redundant since you have a perfectly valid argument for the base case prior in the proof. You could include both approaches for the base case, if just as a "this is what we'd expect" sort of thing, but otherwise I don't see a need. Overall it's alright.